# MySql does not work after upgrading to Yosemite 10.10

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, osx-yosemite

MySql was working properly before upgrading the Yosemite. After doing the upgrade the connection could not be established!

I get the following message from the MySql Workbench:

```
Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at 127.0.0.1:3306:
  Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)
```

When using the terminal to connect, I get the following error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Looks like the db server is not started.

Answer (score 0):

Is MySQL running? Try the likes of the following in terminal:

```
shell> mysqladmin version
shell> ps aux |grep mysql
```

If not, why not? There's a good chance it relates to OS X not allowing StartUp items as of 10.10. In this case, use launchd to control it:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/osx-installation-launchd.html

The linked documentation describes how to set up launchd and also start the MySQL instance. Also, as of this writing, the preference pane does not function on OS X 10.10 (to start/stop mysql) due to the above issue with StartUp. However, it will be fixed in the future.